# Access Firebase Child Node in Node.js - Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

Here is how my Firebase Schema is laid out:
[image]

I am able to index everything except **_geoloc:** into my Algolia Index with this code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Authenticate to Algolia Database.
// TODO: Make sure you configure the `algolia.app_id` and `algolia.api_key` Google Cloud environment variables.
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const client = algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.app_id, functions.config().algolia.api_key);

// Name fo the algolia index for content.
const ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME = 'businessSearch';


exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/businessSearch/{uid}/').onWrite(event => {
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_POSTS_INDEX_NAME);
    const firebaseObject = Object.assign({}, event.data.val(), {
      functions.database.ref('/businessSearch/{uid}/_geoloc').onWrite(event =>{

      })
      objectID: event.params.uid,
    });

    index.saveObject(firebaseObject); // .then or .catch as well
    index.addObject
  });
```

How can I index the **_geoloc:** child node into my Algolia Index with Node.js?

I heard somewhere that this is not possible to index a nested object with Object.assign, but I just wanted to see if it was.

Comment: Very confused as to what you're trying to do here. An `onWrite` on `/businessSearch/{uid}` will include `_geoloc` in its `event.data.val()` payload -- you don't need to listen to the child node separately.

Comment: No, it does not. I am indexing to my Algolia Search Index. Where only the address, businessName, and businessType get Indexed not _geoloc

Comment: This seems like an issue with Algolia, not Firebase. If you do a `console.log(event.data.val())` you ought to see `_geoloc`. Perhaps Algolia ignores underscored fields by default?

Comment: Seems to be a timing issue when the database is updated I manually added another value key pair and _geoloc was then added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timing issue when the database is written and what gets indexed by Algolia. The code included in my question does work with nested objects.